# If methane is pumped into a room, how does it disperse?

Tags: everyday-life, air, gas

So, if methane (natural gas) is slowly pumped into a room containing regular air, does the methane mix uniformly with the air as soon as it's pumped in (immediately expanding to fill it's container), or being lighter, does it first rise to the ceiling in a "cloud" and then slowly start to mix?

Comment: My guess is that this would very much depend on the gas nozzle: if it is a turbulent flow, it will mix right away; in the laminar case it might more or less evenly float to the ceiling first and mix through subsequent air movement. I once did an experiment where nitrogen slowly evaporates off and flows into a loosely sealed box. The nitrogen mixed very evenly almost immediately, it didn't have a higher concentration at the top of the box than at the bottom.

Comment: Let's use the example of a stove burner (not lit) on a low setting as the "pump" in a large room with minimal to no airflow.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to having lower molecular weight than air, methane will be buoyant.  However, don’t expect the blob to rise intact.  The blob will break up as it goes, due to a Rayleigh-Taylor instability.  What’s that?  First think of oil floating on water.  There will be oscillatory gravity waves along the interface, say $\cos (kx-\omega t)$.  Now try to imagine water atop oil.  The disturbance will grow exponentially, like $\cos (kx)\exp (\alpha t)$.

Even in the absence of gravity, the blob of methane wouldn’t just expand, as into a vacuum, because it would almost immediately reach pressure equilibrium with the air.  The methane would have to diffuse through the air.  If *D* denotes its concentration (say partial pressure), then $\dot{D}=\chi {{\nabla }^{2}}D$. The diffusion coefficient $\chi $ is determined by the average speed and mean free path of methane molecules.

Comment: So effectively you're indicating that the majority of the methane would be found at the ceiling, at least in the early stages?

Comment: @JSmith968 Yes indeed, despite breaking up, the blob would head toward the ceiling and spread out, but diffusion would get rid of any sharp boundary between the methane-rich layer and air and would slowly act to homogenize the gases in the room.

Comment: I'm new to this site, so I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place to expand upon this question or not...I'd like to give the specific scenario regarding the methane, the room, and what we're trying to estimate. Should I just start a new thread, or amend this question. Can someone advise? Thanks so much!